# How to bind to style of placeholder of input element in angular?

Tags: angular

How can I achieve something like this in angular?

```
[style.placeholder.color]="active ? 'white' : 'grey'"
```

See to bind placeholder pseudo element of input element. How can I bind to the style property of placeholder of input element?

```
<input type="text" (click)="active = !active" [placeholder]="'hello'" [style.placeholder.color]="active ? 'white' : 'grey'">
```

Comment: I don't think that's even possible. Lets' see...

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You can use @ViewChild(#ref) and then customize the element with renderer2.

Comment: That;s a bit of work. How can I achieve it without viewchild? I mean right within the template!